# Why there is no tag for Causal Inference?

Tags: feature-request, tagging, tag-management

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Responses to the study questions from Causal Inference in Statistics (by Judea Pearl).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078490/responses-to-the-study-questions-from-causal-inference-in-statistics-by-judea-p)

At the moment of posting I found that there is no tag on the forum for Causal Intference.

Causal Inference is a set of powerful methods for data science, economics and business, developed and advocated by one of the most prominent scientists of the field of our times Judea Pearl (Turing award winner). 
Causal Inference courses also have been introduced to the curriculum of many schools (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_inference#Education).

There are several books published recently and the topic will appear more frequently.

This tag should exist.

Comment: I will give a brief remark, and if the OP is interested I'll expand it into an Answer.  More germane to whether a tag is useful on Math.SE than the number of books and papers on a topic is the number of Questions to which the tag would apply.  Some topics in statistical inference are better dealt with at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), which uses the tag `causal-inference` as a synonym for `causality`.  Finally, some such topics carry a bit of philosophical baggage that makes them less amenable to purely mathematical reasoning.

Comment: None of the courses in the link are in departments of mathematics.  They are in statistics, biostatistics, public health, philosophy, political science, and such.  I would guess, for now, questions should be placed in venues such as those.

Comment: @GEdgar I think there are those who would say statistics is a part of maths. Not sure how much I agree, but they certainly are at least tangentially related such that basic questions in statistics fit in MSE.